# I'm Getting no-unsafe-call and no-unsafe-assignment eslint error on imported function even though function is typed

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'm getting no-unsafe-call and also no-unsafe-assignment eslint errors when importing a typed function. If the function is declared in the same file, the error goes away. It seems that eslint is not able to get the return type of the imported function.

In useWorkspaceMessages.ts

```
export interface WorkspaceMessage {
  message: string;
  created: string;
}

export default function useWorkspaceMessages(): WorkspaceMessage[] {
  return [];
}
```

In app.tsx

```
import useWorkspaceMessages, {
  WorkspaceMessage,
} from 'useWorkspaceMessages';

const workspaceMessages: WorkspaceMessage[] = useWorkspaceMessages();
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
error  Unsafe assignment of an any value  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
error  Unsafe call of an any typed value  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
```

If I declare `useWorkspaceMessages` and the `WorkspaceMessage` interface in app.tsx the error goes away.

Comment: Works ok on Node.js and TS 4.0.3

Comment: @Anatoly thanks. Yeah something with my setup might be wrong. I'm on ts 4.1.2 and just set up my dependencies in the last week. Not sure if something is causing eslint no to understand the import types

Comment: Isn't 4.1.2 a beta/dev/unstable version?

Comment: Looks to be latest stable. But either way, I figured it out. I had a mistake .eslint.js parserOptions.project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong. I had a mistake in my `.eslint.js`

my `parserOptions.project` was pointing to te wrong directory for `tsconfig.json`. Sadly, eslint does not complain about this.

Comment: I'm having the same error but as far as I can see my `parserOptions.project` is pointing to the correct `tsconfig.json`. Could you expand your answer with your ESLint and Typescript configurations?