# How to fix Eslint error no-unsafe-call on expect Jasmine function on Angular generated spec file?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, eslint, karma-jasmine

Angular generates (`ng generate service a`) spec files with the following content:

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { AService } from './a.service';

describe('AService', () => {
  let service: AService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(AService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

but Eslint complains with an error (*ESLint: Unsafe call of an `any` typed value.(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call))*) about Jasmine's `expect`:

[image]

How to fix such Eslint error or ignore it on spec files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm Getting no-unsafe-call and no-unsafe-assignment eslint error on imported function even though function is typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64936157/im-getting-no-unsafe-call-and-no-unsafe-assignment-eslint-error-on-imported-fun)

Comment: Thanks for the hint @StavNoy, but no, it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Do you have `@types/jasmine` installed? Can you include your config files? tsConfigs, eslintrc